# SQL Server : group all data by one column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need some help in writing a SQL Server stored procedure. All data group by **Train_B_N**.

[my table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5S76.png)

Expected result :

[expecting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP0VY.png)

```
        with CTE as
        (
            select Train_B_N, Duration,Date,Trainer,Train_code,Training_Program
            from Train_M
            group by Train_B_N
        )

        select
            *
        from Train_M as m
        join CTE as c on c.Train_B_N = m.Train_B_N
```

whats wrong with my query?

Comment: What have you already done and what kind of help do you need?

Comment: Which row do you want to reserve in each group?

Comment: You probably do not understand what `GROUP BY` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` smashes the table together, so having columns that are not GROUPED combine would cause problems with the data.

```
select Train_B_N, Duration,Date,Trainer,Train_code,Training_Program
            from Train_M
            group by Train_B_N
```

By `ANSI` standard, the `GROUP BY` must include all columns that are in the `SELECT` statement which are not in an aggregate function. No exceptions.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT TRAIN_B_N, MAX(DATE) AS Last_Date
FROM TRAIN_M
GROUP BY TRAIN_B_N)

SELECT A.Train_B_N, Duration, Date,Trainer,Train_code,Training_Program
FROM TRAIN_M AS A
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Train_B_N = A.Train_B_N
              AND CTE.Last_Date = A.Date
```

This example would return the last training program, trainer, train_code used by that ID.
This is accomplished from `MAX(DATE)` aggregate function, which kept the greatest (latest) DATE in the table. And since the GROUP BY smashed the rows to their distinct groupings, the JOIN only returns a subset of the table's results.

Keep in mind that `SQL` will return #table_rows X #Matching_rows, and if your #Matching_rows `cardinality` is greater than one, you will get extra rows.

Look up [GROUP BY - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx). I suggest you read everything outside the syntax examples initially and obsorb what the purpose of the clause is.

Also, next time, try googling your problem like this: 'GROUP BY, SQL' or insert the error code given by your `IDE` (`SSMS` or otherwise). You need to understand why things work...and `SO` is here to help, not be your google search engine. ;)

Hope you find this begins your interest in learning all about SQL. :D